# Disable form controls for a set time limit, to prevent incorrect logic

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access, controls

In my program, there is a 'Log Off' option, to log the current user out of the system and return to the log on screen, rather than just exit the whole program.

I've got the database to update correctly when logging off, however, when the main form closes and returns to the log on screen, there is a slight logic bug.

When I enter a username and password, then press 'Log On' and 'Proceed', a `MessageBox` is displayed to show that the current user is already logged on. This is a feature that I implemented, but it shouldn't be showing the message at this point.

After stepping through and checking the database, the user is logged off correctly, but the database hasn't updated quickly enough it seems, so it thinks the user is still logged on.

An example:

I log on as "User1", my test user. The username and password are both "1".

I log off, the code executes.

On the log in screen, I use the following key pattern:
<kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to enter the username and password of 1 in the relevant textboxes.
Then, I use <kbd>Enter</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to trigger the button click events of the log on and proceed buttons.

All in all, this takes maybe a second, 2 seconds max.

However, this triggers the messagebox saying that the user is already logged on.

Yet, if I just enter the username/password and wait a couple of seconds before pressing "Log On", then it works fine - So the database isn't being given time to update is the issue.

So, is there a way to disable the logging on form controls for a second or two, to give the database a chance to commit the changes?

Essentially there are 2 ways I could do this;

- I could delay the main form closing for 2 seconds, before closing/showing the log on form (Tried with an `Application.DoEvents` subroutine, but the log on form just showed anyway, since it is always open in the background
- Or, just show a wait cursor, but disable the textboxes for 2 seconds when it gets focused.

The code for the logging off process:

```
sql = "UPDATE [System Settings] SET usersOnline = ?"
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@users", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = users
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Try
  sql = "UPDATE [Users] SET [isOnline] = ? WHERE User_ID = ?"
  Dim update As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, con)
  update.Parameters.Add("@isOn", OleDb.OleDbType.Boolean).Value = False
  update.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = user
  update.ExecuteNonQuery()
Catch
End Try
```

Log on button code:

```
For Each userRow In mainDBset.Tables(0).Rows
  If userRow.Item("User_ID") = txtUser.Text And userRow.Item("Password") = txtPw.Text Then

    If usersOnline >= maxUsers Then
      MsgBox("Unable to log in, max user limit of '" & maxUsers.ToString & "' has been reached - '" & usersOnline & "' currently logged on.", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Max User Limit Reached")
      Exit Sub
    End If

    sql = "SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [User_ID] = ?"
    Dim checkCMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, mainDBconnection)
    Dim checkAdapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(checkCMD)
    checkAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUser.Text
    Dim cDt As New DataTable
    Dim cDs As New DataSet
    checkAdapter.Fill(cDs)
    cDt = cDs.Tables(0).Copy()

    If cDt.Rows(0).Item("isOnline") = True Then
       MessageBox.Show("This user is already logged into the system, so cannot be logged in again.", "Error Logging On", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
       Exit Sub
    End If
```

Comment: Hmmm... I've never heard of a scenario where this happens, and the database data isn't updated in time... Is there a possibility for you to close the connection, then re-open it when the log on form loads?

Comment: @David Thank you for your suggestion, but no I have already tried this, the database still says the user is logged in. I really need a delay to be in place to prevent it

Comment: So to be clear, you are saying that the call to your update function returns before the update has completed?

Comment: Post up the code attached to both your button clicks. This sounds incorrect.

Comment: @peterG Yes, when the form closes, and I try logging in again, if I don't wait a few seconds, the database is still returning that the user is logged in

Comment: @Minty, the code for the log off process, and log on button is now in the question. Not sure the proceed button code is needed, since that bit doesn't get executed in this instance

Comment: I think to nail this down, my next step would be to write a little test routine that performed both queries one after the other without user intervention. That would prove this odd behaviour. Also I see you have an empty 'catch'  in the logoff - this will swallow any errors which might be giving clues. Also I'm not sure why you are copying the table into cDt.

Comment: @peterG Okay, I ran the queries all one after the other, in the same way, and there was no messagebox... The catch didn't return anything, either, so no errors.

Comment: btw..is con the same connection as mainDBConnection. If not that, could be your delay problem.

Comment: @Trevor It is the same connection, but with a different name. `mainDBconnection` is passed into `frmMain` as a parameter

Comment: I figured it probably was... but had to ask ;)

Comment: You could also try closing and re-opening the connection after the logout. That should clear any pending operations or caching issues.

Comment: @Trevor Just tried that, the same result occurred.

Comment: weird then.... Have you tried breaking after the execute command and looking at the DB with another tool to see if it changes.

Comment: @Trevor When I put a breakpoint on `update.ExecuteNonQuery()`, I can step that command, check the DB table, the value has updated. Then there is no issue with logging on straight after, so again it seems like stepping over it is fine because the stepping/checking provides a long enough delay.

Comment: One thing that looks odd to me about your code... you are using ? type parameters in the query string then you use named parameters in the adds... I have no idea what affect that will have on the delay, but something to try....

Comment: @Trevor That's how all of my queries are done, not sure it will make a difference at all

Comment: well other than the query compiler has to go look for the named parameters first then default back to order...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue.

The issue was because I was hiding the log on form when showing the main form, so when the main form closed, the logon form was still using the same connection and the same values, properties, etc as when it closed.

This meant even with blank textboxes, the user was able to log straight in again.

To fix the issue, I disposed of the connection when closing the form, then reset the values and re-loaded the form after the `.ShowDialog()` call in the proceed button click event.

Took A LOT of debugging, and not easy to explain, but closing the connection and re-loading the form to it's original state fixed the issue, basically.